# Add margins/white space on left of form?

Tags: infopath

I have a form that I designed in InfoPath. When I created the form, it was created with no margins. I'm trying to get a margin to show up on the left of my form, but it looks like when I go to the view menu, I can only set margins for printing.

Any thoughts?

I can add blank space on the right of the form by just expanding it (it seems like it's a table cell? Maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty form has a table by default. Cell padding can be used to achieve this. Please see below the cell padding setting 50px as an example.

[image]